# FetchbaseQuery invalidate cache

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have 2 completely independent components without any parent-child relationship being displayed on a single page.

Component 1 : Makes an API call fetches some records and display it in a table having server side-pagination

Component 2 : Contains a form, when the user submits the form the data in the component 1 needs to be refetch-ed through the backend.

Since I am using fetchBaseQuery to query the data, I believe I need to invalidate the cache in order to make the API call in the component 1.

I tried `refetch()` to fulfil that requirement but got no luck. I also tried setting the cache timeout using `keepUnusedDataFor` that too didn't work. Also, tried to do something with the tags, but for that I will have to use `mutation` instead of `query` and I am not sure how mutation is useful as per my use case

Here's some of the code :

**component1.tsx**

```js
let { data, error, isSuccess, isError, isFetching, refetch } = useGetQuery(request, { skip});
  const records = data?.records;

 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (records) {
      // set records within table
    }
  }, [records]);
```

**useGetQuery.ts**

```js
const extendedApi = mainApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getQuery: builder.query<response, request>({
      query: (request?: request) => ({
        url: "someURL",
        body: request,
        method: "POST",
      }),
      providesTags: ["Requests"],
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: true,
});

export const { useGetQuery } = extendedApi;
```

**component2.tsx**

```js
let [trigger, data] = useSubmitFormMutation();
const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    trigger(// Some Object);
}
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isSuccess) {
      updateRefreshRecords(true); // setting the hook to true to make an API call in component 1
    }
  }, [isSuccess]);
```

**useSubmitFormMutation.ts**

```js
const extendedApi = mainApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    submitForm: builder.mutation<response, request>({
      query: (request?: request) => ({
        url: "some_other_url",
        body: request,
        method: "POST",
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Requests"],
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: false,
});

export const { useSubmitFormMutation } = extendedApi;
```

**mainAPI.ts**

```js
export const dynamicBaseQuery: BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  const { mainApiUrl } = (api.getState() as RootState).settings.endpoints;
  const rawBaseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: mainApiUrl,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      // Use getState to pull the jwtToken and pass it in the headers to the api endpoint.
      const { jwtToken } = (getState() as RootState).auth;
      headers.set("authorization", jwtToken);

      return headers;
    },
  });
  return rawBaseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
};

export const mainApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "mainApi",
  baseQuery: dynamicBaseQuery,
  endpoints: () => ({}),
  tagTypes: ["Requests"],
});
```

**store.ts**

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    // other reducers
    [localApi.reducerPath]: localApi.reducer,
    [mainApi.reducerPath]: mainApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    })
      .concat(localApi.middleware)
      .concat(mainApi.middleware),
});
```

Can you please help me how can I invalidate the cache as per my use case.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `invalidatesTags` to your mutation and that should refresh the query:

```js
const extendedApi = mainApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    submitForm: builder.mutation<response, request>({
      query: (request?: request) => ({
        url: "some_other_url",
        body: request,
        method: "POST",
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Requests"]
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: false,
});
```

No need for manual refetching or `keepUnusedDataFor`.

If that doesn't work, double-check that you added the api's `middleware` to the middlewares in your `configureStore`

Comment: Tried the above mentioned approach but the API in the `Component1.tsx` didn't trigger and refetch the records automatically.

Comment: Did you make sure that the middleware is in `configureStore`? Please share your store configuration. Other than that, do you have any logs on your console (assuming you are on the development build)?

Comment: Added the store config in the post itself, Yes I am on build env but there is no error logs if that what you are asking for

Comment: Sorry I misread your code. `submitForm` **has to be a mutation**. You should never make anything that changes data on the server a query. (a query will also not invalidate)

Comment: yeah I converted that into the mutation, still facing the same issue

Comment: please update the ticket with your current code

Comment: I don't have time to chat right now. You can always ask the redux channel on reactiflux

Comment: You still seem to be using `useSubmitFormQuery` there? But generally: I'd really recommend the reactiflux chat - we can still update here if we found the issue.

Comment: Was not using `useSubmitFormQuery` forgot to update that part, have also asked on the reactiflux chat.

Comment: thanks for all the help and support for solving this problem, agreed the code was then correct and the issue was then because of the skip token. Somehow the value for skip was getting set to true due to which it was not making a API to re-fetch once the cache is-invalidated

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your `submitForm` endpoint to `mutation` type and invalidate *"Requests"* tag on this endpoint. This way you don't have to use `updateRefreshRecords`.

You can then *remove* below `useEffect` in `Component1.tsx`

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (refreshRecords) {
      refetch();
    }
  }, [refreshRecords]);
```

and also remove `keepUnusedDataFor: 5`, from `getQuery` endpoint

> I am not sure how mutation is useful as per my use case

When form is submitted, you are either creating or updating some data on backend. So, `mutation` is the right type of endpoint here. Use `query` type endpoint when you want to fetch some data from backend.

Comment: Tried the above mentioned approach but the API in the `Component1.tsx` didn't trigger and refetch the records automatically.

Comment: I just noticed that you are passing skipToken for `useGetQuery` in your `Component1.tsx`. Can you try removing that.

Comment: the skip token was intendedly passed in order to skip the first API call when the component renders, the skip is set to false when required, but now I have completely removed that part & used mutation instead, still got no luck.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out to remove the skipToken, the issue was then because of that only. Somehow the value for skip was getting set to true due to which it was not making a API to re-fetch once the cache is-invalidated